# How to use JSX properly for react, i'm getting an error

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in ReactJs n my first code test. The tuto says that this will work:

HTML(index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>react test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <!-- Load React. -->
    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

    <!-- Load our React code -->
    <script src="pba.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

JS(pba.js):

```
const element = {<h1>Hello, world!</h1>};
ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Problem:

pba.js:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: `<h1>...</h1`> should be inside parenthesis, not curly brackets. Also, you need a tool that will transform your `React` code into something that a browser can understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a build tool like 
`create react-app`, `gatsby` or `next.js`
What you are doing here is loading a javascript file directly into an html document. 
However the Javascript file has no idea, what React is. If you don't want to use an independent build tool like suggested above, you can use `webpack` to bundle your code.

Here is a tutorial on how to do this: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/babel/

otherwise look into `create react app`:
https://www.google.com/search?q=create+react+app&oq=create+react+app&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.3442j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Your element component needs to be a function or a class component. **Note** that doing the following will also work, but using one component as a root component for your app is better than just rendering one element.

```
const greeting = 'Hello World';

const element = <h1>{greeting}</h1>;
// or const Element = [<h1>{greeting}</h1>, <h1>Hello again</h1>];
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Using function/class component

```
// pba.js
const Element = () => (<h1>Hello World</h1>)
ReactDOM.render(<Element />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and also you need to add babel cdn to transpile your react code, add type `text/babel` to your script tag. `<script type="text/babel" src="pba.js"></script>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>react test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <!-- Load React. -->
    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Load our React code -->
    <script type="text/babel" src="pba.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `element` doesn't need to be a `function` or a `class`.

Answer (score 0):

While this is possible, there are a couple of things wrong with your code.

- It looks like goto1 is correct, you can just use the `()` syntax for this, but you need to use `()` instead of `{}`
- While goto1 is correct, the first argument in `ReactDOM.render(...)` does **not** *have* to be a function or class (just valid `JSX`), I am 110% recommending you stick to using functions or classes...
- You need to use something like [Babel Standalone](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone) so your React code can be translated into something a browser will understand

I have made a lot of comments with examples in the demo below, which should help you out.

**Demo:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>react test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="root-two"></div>

    <!-- Load React. -->
    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <!-- Load Babel Standalone -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Load our React code -->
    <!-- Notice the 'type="text/babel"' attribute -->
    <script type="text/babel"> 
        // This was done for the sake of simplicity, you can still load your .js file here

        // While goto1 is technically correct, I recommend sticking 
        // to using functions or classes..
        const Element = () => {
          return ( <h1>Hello, world!</h1> );
        }

        // This means you can do things like:
        // Notice our component from above, Element, is reusable here..
        const AnotherElement = () => {
          return ( 
            <div style={{textAlign: 'center', color: 'blue'}}>
              <Element />
            </div> 
          );
        }
        
        // Keep in mind using `()` syntax versus a function or class, means this is not reusable at all..
        // The following is NOT reusable!
        // const element = ( <h1>Hello, world!</h1> );
        
        // You could also drop the `()` as it is used to group lines of code,
        // something like this is also not reusable (but would still work in
        // this scenario)!
        // const element = <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        
        // For example, this wouldnt work
        // const anotherElement = ( <element /> );
        
        // This would also not work
        // class SomeClass extends React.Component {
        //   render() { return ( <div><element /></div> ) }
        // }
        
        // This would not work either
        // const SomeComponent = () => {
        //   return ( <div><element /></div> );
        // }
        
        ReactDOM.render(
            // goto1 is correct, it looks like you can use an object as you were.
            // Please be mindful of this as it is not reusable!
            // I recommend sticking to either functions or classes, until you are more comfortable with React
            <Element />,
            document.getElementById('root')
        );

        // For the second example, demonstrating how using functions or classes 
        // is reusable, whereas your original example was not:
        ReactDOM.render(
          <AnotherElement />,
          document.getElementById('root-two')
        );
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `element` does not have to be a `class` or a `function`. The way he has it it'd work assuming he used `()` instead of `{}` and used `babel`.

Comment: @goto1 Good looking out! I appreciate that, I have updated my answer.  Care to elaborate on why using `()` vs `{}` will work? Is it because using `{}` means you're instantiating a key/value object?

Comment: Using `{}` wouldn't even be a valid syntax. `ReactDOM.render` takes a "React element" and according to the docs it can be "either a tag name string (such as 'div' or 'span'), a React component type (a class or a function), or a React fragment type." `const element = (<div/>)` is valid JSX that gets converted to the same output you'd get by using `React.createElement`, so it's totally fine. See here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement and here https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#rendering-an-element-into-the-dom.

Comment: Right - using `()` is just an easy way to group lines of code together.. Fully aware of `{}` being incorrect syntax in this scenario... Keep in mind, using `()` works, but it means that code is *not* reusable.. which kind of defeats the purpose (which, in this case, you don't even have to use `()`....doing:  `const element = <h1>Hello, world!</h1>` is the same thing).  However, technically, you are still correct - the first argument in `ReactDOM.render(...)` does **not** have to be either a function or class - just valid `jsx`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your pba.js file as follows:

```
const element = React.createElement("h1", {}, "Hello, world!");

ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById("root"));
```